# Compile LESS file into CSS Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, bootswatch

I have a LESS file which I want to compile to use as my bootstrap theme. How can I compile it? Is there a place where I can do this?

The less FILE comes from http://bootswatchr.com/ but when I click the link get CSS and choose either minified version or complete version, nothing happens.

I have the LES file from the left pane, is there a way I can still compile it?

Comment: If you're not into the whole command line thing ... this is a free and easy to use app for compiling less: http://crunchapp.net/

Comment: Did you try `grunt dist`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. [Install node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. Install the Less compiler: `npm install -g less`
3. Run the Less compiler on your Less source to produce CSS: `lessc your-source.less > output.css`  More info: http://lesscss.org/#using-less

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebStrom IDE, then it has a plugin for LESS to compile. I have been using the plugin to compile the LESS over a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you want software, then I would recommend [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless). You can use it on OSX/Win. It has drag and drop support which is nice and will tell you if your syntax is wrong. It also updates to support the latest LESS version.

Comment: Today, SimpLESS is deprecated. They stopped to update their software so now the new features provided by Less (1.4) are unrecognized.

Comment: I would assume most people on here would recognize the post date and do some research :)

Bootstrap is getting rid of native LESS anyway with B4.

Comment: It was just to inform because I tried, it's a pity because SimpLESS was a great software.